# Using MSBuild, how do I set a property to the contents of a file?

Tags: msbuild

I have a file that I set using PowerShell that contains the version number of my build.  I need to get this within MSBuild so I can act on it within my build script.  It seems simple enough; I just want to take the contents of the file and set a property to that value.

I thought maybe doing an Exec task, doing a "more" on my file, and capturing standard out would do the trick, but I can't seem to get this to work.  It appears that others have had problems with stdout and MSBuild as well.  Here is what I have tried:

```
<Exec Command="more $(BuildDirectory)\version.txt" Outputs="stdout">
    <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="BuildNumber" />
</Exec>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [ReadLinesFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299.aspx) task is what you want

```
<ReadLinesFromFile File="Version.Txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="BuildNumber"/>
</ReadLinesFromFile>
```

that said, another way to do what your question implies is to store you build num info in an xml file, with a MSBuild schema

something like

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
   <BuildNumber>10</BuildNumber>
   <RevNumber>5</RevNumber>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and then import the version.properties file into your main msbuild file

Comment: Thanks!  I just couldn't find that task.  FYI, there is a slight bug in your first code snippet.  It is ItemName instead of Item:

    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(BuildDirectory)\version.txt">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="BuildNumber" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

Then I can access the output using "@(BuildNumber)".

Comment: Ack - now I need to change from a list item (@) to a property ($).  Any tips on this?

Comment: I think I figured it out:
<CreateProperty Value="@(BuildNumber)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="BuildNumberValue" />
</CreateProperty>

Comment: Use the `PropertyName` attribute in the `Output` element to directly create a property in the `ReadLinesFromFile` task.